# ERR : Can't update table 'articulos' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

***Resulta que tengo el siguiente ejercicio :*** 6. Hacer un trigger que si al insertar un nuevo artículo el código del proveedor no lo tenemos dado de alta debe poner el código de proveedor 0000.

Lo estoy intentado de todas las manera ha mandado 13 ejercicio el cual voy por el 6 y no se porque no me funciona.

***Mi código :***

```
USE almacen;
DELIMITER $$
DROP trigger IF EXISTS codprov $$
CREATE trigger codprov AFTER INSERT on articulos
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE VAR VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT '0000';
    SELECT proveedores.cod_prov INTO VAR FROM proveedores,articulos WHERE proveedores.cod_prov=articulos.cod_prov AND proveedores.cod_prov=NEW.cod_prov AND cod_art=NEW.cod_art LIMIT 1;
    IF (VAR <> NEW.cod_prov) THEN
        UPDATE articulos SET cod_prov='0000' WHERE cod_art=NEW.cod_art;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Prueba</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/231)

El objetivo de este ejercicio es que si el código del proveedor no existe cuando lo inserto pues se reemplace por 0000.

***Por ejemplo :*** Yo inserto lo siguiente

Tabla ARTICULO(cod_art,DESCRIPCION,PRECIO,STOCK,CADUCIDAD,**cod_prov**,Observaciones)

```
INSERT INTO articulos VALUES('DR-007','Lejia',0.80,18,FALSE,'A002','Muy Toxica'); #Este proveedor existe por lo que no se cambia su codigo que es A002
insert into articulos values('DR-008','',3,3,false,'A005',''); #Este proveedor no existe por lo que se sustituye A0005 por 0000
```

Comment: Primero te lo dejo para que lo investigues [en el sitio](/search?q=already+used+by+statement+which+invoked+this+stored+function%2Ftrigger).

Comment: vale solucionado ya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resulta que no puedo hacer un ***INSERT*** y un ***UPDATE*** al mismo tiempo.

***Solución :*** En lugar de usar ***update*** use un ***SET*** y con eso me valió aparte no era ***after*** si no ***before***

```
USE almacen;
DELIMITER $$
DROP trigger IF EXISTS codprov $$
CREATE trigger codprov BEFORE INSERT on articulos
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE VAR VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT '0000';
    SELECT proveedores.cod_prov INTO VAR FROM proveedores,articulos WHERE proveedores.cod_prov=articulos.cod_prov AND proveedores.cod_prov=NEW.cod_prov AND cod_art=NEW.cod_art LIMIT 1;
    IF (VAR <> NEW.cod_prov) THEN
        SET NEW.cod_prov='0000';
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

***Luego de esto Inserto los datos :***

```
INSERT INTO articulos VALUES('DR-008','',3,3,false,'A005','');
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Prueba</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/234)