# Hacer un INSERT y un UPDATE al mismo tiempo en MariaDB - InnoDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Estoy algo confundido con este tema; estoy queriendo insertar un registro y al mismo tiempo hacer un update en la misma tabla mediante un trigger. Estoy trabajando en MariaDB, les paso el código del trigger y el código de error 1442 que dice (Can't update table 'compras' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger).
Ese mismo código tengo realizado en Postgres y no me da ningún problema.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `ft_comercial`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `tg_pupi`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `tg_pupi` AFTER INSERT ON `compras` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
`compras` SET `estado` = 'bb' WHERE `id_compra` <> new.`id_compra` AND `id_producto` = new.`id_producto`;   
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: No puedes aplicar un trigger que afecte la misma tabla que dispara el trigger :)

Comment: Gracias por responder @Alfabravo pero en Postgres tengo uno igual.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."t_cambiaestado_provi"()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$

begin 


 UPDATE providencia   SET  estado = 2 WHERE id_documentos = new.id_documentos AND id_providencia  <>  new.id_providencia ;


 return NEW ;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100

Comment: Esa es una trigger function. Es diferente. Que la implementación de una caracteríßtica en una DBMS sea de una forma no significa que _tiene_ que funcionar en otras.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración @Alfabravo

Comment: @Paco si quieres realizar un update y un insert puedes usar SET en lugar del update te viene bien ya que actualiza los datos de la tabla o realizar una función que actualiza o un procedimiento.

Comment: @JavierG.Raya muchas gracias por contribuir, infinita gracias a todos.

Comment: @JavierG.Raya listo señor.

Comment: @Alfabravo ya lo acabo de solucionar :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

El problema es que no puedes hacer un ***INSERT*** y luego un ***UPDATE*** para la misma tabla si quieres actualizar algún elemento usa ***SET*** simplemente :-)

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `ft_comercial`$$

DROP TRIGGER `tg_pupi` IF EXISTS `tg_pupi`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `tg_pupi` AFTER INSERT ON `compras` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
     IF (id_compra <> new.id_compra) AND (id_producto = new.id_producto) THEN
          SET `new.estado` = 'bb';
     END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Gracias Javier!.

Comment: De nada si es posible, vótala positivamente con ^ @Paco (-:

Comment: Listo señor, muchas gracias por la amabilidad javier.

Comment: De nada amigo :-)

Comment: Si os fijáis, y tal vez sea un error al plantear la pregunta, los `estados` que hay que actualizar a `bb` son precisamente los de las demás compras en las que coincida el producto, no la que acaba de ser insertada. Con el trigger de @JavierG.Raya únicamente se actualiza el del registro recién insertado :(

Comment: @JavierG.Raya Fíjate en que, al dispararse en un `INSERT`, únicamente afecta al registro recién insertado. Esa condición nunca se cumplirá...

Comment: ahora que lo pienso se puede solucionar con una función que la llame en el trigger, pero de todos modos al usuario le funciona a lo mejor llama en el set alguna función y si se cumple se cambia yo tengo varios ejercicios realizados asi @DavidJP

Comment: Tampoco :) Todo lo que afecte a la tabla que activa el trigger está restringido. Yo le preguntaría al OP qué realidad está modelando para rediseñar la solución. Si con un disparador no se puede, habrá que buscar otra forma de conseguir lo que busca. ¿Para qué quiere poner esos estados a `bb`? Igual el estado debería estar en el producto y no en la compra. Guardando el id de la última compra, por ejemplo. Así sí se podría resolver con un disparador...

Comment: ***Por ejemplo :*** en mi [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529104/err-cant-update-table-articulos-in-stored-function-trigger-because-it-is-al) me paso lo mismo lo solucione asi algo parecido con un if y me lo dio por bueno el maestro. Y como solo necesito comprobar el registro recientemente metido pues funciona

Comment: Y si te fijas usa el alia ***NEW*** por lo que quiere el nuevo valor @DavidJP :-)

Answer (score 2):

Como con un disparador no se pueden modificar otros registros de la misma tabla, habrá que buscar otra forma de conseguir lo que se busca.

Colocando el estado en el producto y no en la compra, y guardando el `id` de la última compra, por ejemplo, sí se podría resolver con un disparador.

Vamos resolverlo partiendo de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
  id_producto int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  producto varchar(15),
  estado varchar(15),
  id_ultima_compra int
  );
CREATE TABLE compras (
  id_compra int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_producto int DEFAULT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_producto) REFERENCES productos(id_producto)
);
ALTER TABLE productos
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_ultima_compra) REFERENCES compras(id_compra);
INSERT INTO productos (producto) VALUES
  ('Tomates'),('Lechugas');
```

Definimos el disparador:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_compras
  AFTER INSERT ON compras
  FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE productos
    set estado='bb',id_ultima_compra=NEW.id_compra
    WHERE id_producto=NEW.id_producto;
```

Y probamos a realizar estas inserciones:

```
INSERT INTO compras (id_producto) VALUES
  (1),(1),(1),(1);
```

Como el estado del producto ya no están en `compras`, habrá que acceder a esa información con esta consulta:

```
SELECT id_compra,id_producto,producto,
  IF(id_compra=id_ultima_compra,NULL,estado) estado_compra
  FROM compras
  JOIN productos USING(id_producto);
```

Obteniendo algo así:

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+---------------+
| id_compra | id_producto | producto | estado_compra |
+-----------+-------------+----------+---------------+
|         1 |           1 | Tomates  | bb            |
|         2 |           1 | Tomates  | bb            |
|         3 |           1 | Tomates  | bb            |
|         4 |           1 | Tomates  | NULL          |
+-----------+-------------+----------+---------------+
```

Y, ya por curiosidad, ¿para qué necesitas algo así?

Comment: Hola David, en realidad fue una necesidad que surgió por la situación de agarrar un proyecto de tercero que esta desarrollado en PHP, pero está realizado con PHPMaker que es un generador de código PHP (valga la redundancia), el citado proyecto tenía la opción de insertar varias veces el mismo producto que al mismo tiempo debía inactivar el producto anterior del mismo id. Era muy extraño todo sinceramente.
Te agradezco a vos y a todas las personas que me ayudaron con este tema. Un abrazo.

Comment: Algo así sospechaba... Entonces, ¿es lo que buscabas?

Comment: Si, me ayudaste bastante, muchas gracias.

Comment: @Paco En ese caso, marca como correcta la respuesta que haya resuelto tu problema. No vayamos a confundir a alguien que se encuentre en una situación parecida... :)

Answer (score -1):

Básicamente, existen dos métodos para agregar registros a una tabla. El primero consiste en agregar un registro cada vez, el segundo consiste en agregar varios registros a la vez. En ambos casos, se usa la instrucción SQL INSERT INTO para llevar a cabo la tarea. Las instrucciones INSERT INTO se suelen denominar "consultas de datos anexados".

Para agregar un registro a una tabla, debe usar la lista de campos para definir en qué campos se colocarán los datos y, luego, proporcionar los datos en una lista de valores. Para definir la lista de valores, use la cláusula VALUES. Por ejemplo, la siguiente instrucción inserta los valores “1”, “Kelly” y “Jill” en los campos CustomerID, Last Name y First Name, respectivamente.

Comment: Un poco turbio el contenido anterior de la respuesta...